# Implementing two cells click functions in same row using single cell click event

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView with three columns.

I have implemented a function in the DataGridView cell click event for one cell in one row. If I click on that cell then the corresponding row values will be transferred to another form. That works.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender,DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
}
```

My problem is that I want to implement another function for another cell being clicked in same row. Can I implement this function in same click event (as I have mentioned above) or is there another process I need to follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DataGridViewCellEventArgs` can be used to determine what the position of that cell in the grid is:

```
DataGridViewCell cell = (DataGridViewCell) dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];

if (cell.ColumnIndex == this.dataGridView1.Columns["YourColumn"].Index)
{
    // Do something when a "YourColumn" cell is clicked
}
else if (cell.ColumnIndex == this.dataGridView1.Columns["AnotherColumn"].Index)
{
    // Do something when an "AnotherColumn" cell is clicked
}
```

This way you can provide different behaviour, according to what cell is clicked.